# How to use TagHelpers in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, blazor

I created a tag helper and wanted to use that in my Blazor sample project.
However, when I want to use the tag helper, the compiler complains about that:

`CS0103 The name 'StartTagHelperWritingScope' does not exist in the current context FirstBlazorApp`.

What is additionally required to make tag helpers work in Blazor?

Comment: Did you include a using.. for the namespace of the taghelper?

Comment: Yes, besides the `@using` I also have the `@addTagHelper` directive there. The error messages comes at compilation time, as soon as I actually want to use the tag helper.

Answer (score 9):

### Update: Integrating Razor components into Razor Pages and MVC apps in a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app is supported in ASP.NET Core in .NET 5.0 or later. (Microsoft Docs)

Tag helpers are not supported in Blazor. At least not as of now.

Comment: Seems to be the case :/  What's confusing is the default project layout contains a directive for taghelpers: `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Comment: What options exist in Blazor to achieve an attribute-based tag helper.  E.g. Tag helpers can be invoked with the existence of a specific attribute, and then rewrite the output.  Blazor components are geared towards element output.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I just discovered you can use Partial Components inside of Razor Components. So if you want to use tag helpers, move the elements that need them to a partial and include it in the Razor Component.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but could you post an example?

Answer (score 3):

On A blazor page you would use a blazor component, this is like a TagHelper but it runs client side and is like an Angular component (or similar in any other client side JS framework) is that respect. TagHelpers run on the Server and blazor components run on the client, both allow you to create new tags. a simple component in the blazor same is the NavMenu which lives currently in the Shared folder.

Comment: Furthermore, Razor Components (the component model of Blazor) are not your typical Razor implementation. Unlike HTML Helpers or Tag Helpers, Razor Components are compiled to a C# class. Where HTML Helper and Tag Helper are utilities for generating strings (HTML), Razor Components product Render Trees.